# Loading URLs from JSON to SDWebimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, sdwebimage

I'm really new and curious to iOS development and been following guides, readme docs and tutorials trying to work on a small little side project. I have the following class which works really well in printing the `json` data off a web server, I can see the `json` data printed in my console in Xcode, however I would like to use `SDWebimage` to load/cache the images off the `json` data and into my `UIImageView` which is inside my `UICollectionView` - both of which I created in storyboard for this class.

Can someone point me in the right direction? As it stands my `UICollectionView` is just empty when I load the following:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class TopratedVC: BaseViewController {

        @IBOutlet var collectionview: UICollectionView!

    //Our web service url
    let URL_GET_coffeemugs:String = "http://coffeemugs.com/ios/feed.php"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //SDWebimage stuff
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        //created NSURL
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_GET_coffeemugs)

        //creating NSMutableURLRequest
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

        //setting the method to post
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        //creating a task to send the post request
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            data, response, error in

            //exiting if there is some error
            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }

            //parsing the response
            do {
                guard let coffeemugs = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray else {
                    //Doesn't exist, or isn't an NSArray
                    return
                }

                for coffeemug in coffeemugs {
                    //getting the data at each index
                    let coffeemugName = coffeemug["name"] as! String
                    let coffeemugDirectLink = coffeemug["direct_link"] as! String
                    let coffeemugImage = coffeemug["image"] as! String

                    //displaying the data
                    print("name -> ", coffeemugName)
                    print("direct_link -> ", coffeemugDirectLink)
                    print("image -> ", coffeemugImage)
                    print("===================")
                    print()
                }            

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        //executing the task
        task.resume()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I tried to load it using the method below but that didn't result in loading the images:

```
 NSString *imageString = [[_imgurArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"direct_link"];
 [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];
 cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Comment: Does `coffeemug["image"]` holds the image url string?

Comment: Both `coffeemugDirectLink` and `coffeemugImage` are the URL of the image actually.

Comment: What does `_imgurArray ` holds? Is this the copy of `coffeemugs ` or hold url string of images only?

Comment: Coffeemugs is where the data is, should not have used _imgurArray  initially.

Comment: How you initilise `_imgurArray `?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
NSString *imageString = [[_imgurArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"direct_link"];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];
```

but this will resize your imageview when image will be download so better add a uiimageview of prefered in your cell (stroyboard) then make a iboutlet now you can use

```
NSString *imageString = [[_imgurArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"direct_link"];
    [cell.yourImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageString]];
```

Thanks (:

Comment: Khatri can you please point me in the location as to where I should use the above codes?

Comment: use them in your cellForRowAtIndex:

Comment: I don't have  `cellForRowAtIndex` can you please show me an example of how I might achieve this?

Comment: sorry sorry i mean cellForItemAtIndexPath: where you are configuring your UICollectionView's Cell

Comment: I haven't configured UICollectionView's cell apart form inside the storyboard, where can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Use SDWebImage with option **SDWebImageRetryFailed** e.g.

```
    [YOUR_IMAGEVIEW sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:subCategoryImageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed];
```